# Where is a good place/way to store Windows config files for Python scripts?

Tags: python, windows, configuration, configparser

I have a script/program I am working on that requires a configuration file (I am using `ConfigParser`).  On linux, I will default to store these variables in `~/.myscript` using the `os.getenv('HOME')` function.

With Windows, I know I can use `os.getenv('USERPROFILE')` to find the User's "home" directory, however, is it a good idea to save a *hidden* file that way (ie, with the name `.myscript`)?

I don't use Windows, obviously, but wanted to be smart about it for those who do.

Is there a standard place/way to store these config variables on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.environ['AppData']
```

It's usual to create a folder inside with your organisation name and put any files inside that. There's no need to ‘hide’ the files, and `.` at the start of a filename isn't valid in Windows.

Or put the settings in the [registry](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice - `AppData` seems fine to me (then, after I work through which os is being used, the rest of the functions can access the data the same).